# How do you view page source using Watir?

Tags: ruby, browser, watir

I need to be able to go straight to a page's source code using Watir.
For example, "view-source:www.amazon.com".

However, `browser.goto("view-source:www.amazon.com")` does not work. I can't just extract a page's source code because I am injecting javascript and extracting the source code only provides the original source code of the page.

How do I get around this? Is there a way to type anything I want in to the address bar using Watir? Or does it have to be a valid URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the solution is browser dependent.

In Firefox, you need to put the full path (ie include the 'http'):

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto('view-source:http://www.amazon.com/')
```

In Chrome, it works as you had originally written it:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto('view-source:www.amazon.com')
```

In Internet Explorer, the 'view-source' URI is not supported (at least for the later versions). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View-source_URI_scheme.

Comment: I can't get chromedriver to work. Do you know if it works on Windows 7?

Comment: I was using Windows 7 with Chrome when I tested the above code.